# Code not printing what I seek

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the first bit, as I print out the "ask2", it prints out "exit" as opposed to the licence plate that it's supposed to be printing.

```
     ask = input("-Would you like to 1 input an existing number plate\n--or 2 view a random number\n1 or 2: ")
        ask2 = ""
        plate = ""
        if int(ask) == 1:
            ask2 = ""
            print("========================================================================")
            while ask2 != 'exit':
                ask2 = input ("Please enter it in such form (XX00XXX): ").lower()
                # I had no idea that re existed, so I had to look it up.
                # As your if-statement with re gave an error, I used this similar method for checking the format.
                # I cannot tell you why yours didn't work, sorry.
                valid = re.compile("[a-z][a-z]\d\d[a-z][a-z][a-z]\Z")
                                   #b will start and end the program, meaning no more than 3-4 letters will be used.
                # The code which tells the user to enter the right format (keeps looping)
                # User can exit the loop by typing 'exit'
                while (not valid.match(ask2)) and (ask2 != 'exit'):
                    print("========================================================================")
                    print("You can exit the validation by typing 'exit'.")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print("========================================================================")
                    ask2 = input("Or stick to the rules, and enter it in such form (XX00XXX): ").lower()
                if valid.match(ask2):
                    print("========================================================================\nVerification Success!")
                    ask2 = 'exit'  # People generally try to avoid 'break' when possible, so I did it this way (same effect)

**print("The program, will determine whether or not the car "+str(plate),str(ask)+" is travelling more than the speed limit")**
```

Also I am looking for a few good codes that are good for appending (putting the data in a list), and printing. 
This is what I've done;

```
  while tryagain not in ["y","n","Y","N"]:
        tryagain = input("Please enter y or n")
    if tryagain.lower() == ["y","Y"]:
        do_the_quiz()
    if tryagain==["n","N"]:
        cars.append(plate+": "+str(x))

print(cars)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post *only* the relevant code portion, and be more specific with your question: when you're asking "why does it print x?" make sure to show us which line in the code does so, what was the input that you provided and etc. Good luck!

Comment: You say ask2 is printing out as 'exit', but I don't see anywhere in the code you posted that actually prints out ask2.  I do see that you are setting ask2 to 'exit' if `valid.match(ask2)` is true; perhaps that is why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print `ask2` it prints 'exit' because you set it to exit with `ask2 = 'exit'`, and your loop cannot terminate before `ask2` is set to 'exit'.

You could use `ask2` for the user's input, and another variable `loop` to determine when to exit the loop. For example:

```
loop = True
while loop:
    # ...
    if valid.match(ask2) or ask2 == 'exit':
        loop = False
```

I am not quite sure what your other block of code is trying to achieve, but the way that you test `tryagain` is incorrect, it will never be equal to a two element list such as `["y","Y"]`, perhaps you meant to use `in`?, This change shows one way to at least fix that problem:

```
while tryagain not in ["y","n","Y","N"]:
    tryagain = input("Please enter y or n")
if tryagain.lower() == "y":
    do_the_quiz()
else:
    cars.append(plate+": "+str(x))

print(cars)
```